# 403 Client Error: Invalid or non-existent authentication information while uploading to Pypi with twine

Tags: python, upload, http-status-code-403, pypi, twine

**403 Client Error: Invalid or non-existent authentication information occurs when uploading new module to pypi with Twine**

Win10 Pro 1803 Biuld 17134.1069 64 bit // Python 3.7.5 32 bit // pip 19.3.1

I successfully created tar. and whl. in the dist folder, registered on https://pypi.org/ with e-mail confirmation and started to upload.

I checked both files with command line ('PASSED')

and did the following:

```
Uploading distributions to https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
Enter your username: gakonorde
Enter your password:
Uploading gersyll-Alpha.release-py3-none-any.whl
100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 6.43k/6.43k [00:01<00:00, 5.12kB/s]
NOTE: Try --verbose to see response content.
HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Invalid or non-existent authentication information. for url: https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
```

The command line does not allow me to enter password after username. I only can press ENTER.

I tried also

```
Password for 'your-username' in 'https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/':
```

... and again, I can press nothing except of ENTER.

Then I created *.pypirc* file with credentials for https://pypi.org/ and its test version and run `python -m twine upload dist/*` again

I was not asked for a password, but got the same error:

```
Uploading distributions to https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
Uploading gersyll-Alpha.release-py3-none-any.whl
100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 6.43k/6.43k [00:01<00:00, 5.46kB/s]
NOTE: Try --verbose to see response content.
HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Invalid or non-existent authentication information. for url: https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
```

When I combine *.pypirc* with API token, the problem remains the same.

I can enter my account on https://pypi.org/, so it obviously exists (and e-mail is verified).

I also added the second e-mail, verified and set it as primary (nothing changed).

Here is my setup.py:

```
import setuptools

with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

setuptools.setup(
    name="gersyll",
    version="Alpha release",
    author="gakonorde",
    author_email="gabrielko@yandex.ru",
    description="This module counts the number of words of different syllable length for all texts in a directory",
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    url="https://github.com/gakonorde/gersyll",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.7",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
    python_requires='>=3.7',
)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**
The .pypirc file is in the same folder as .setup, README, License, dict/ etc.

It's content is as follows:

```
[distutils]
index-servers =
  pypi
  pypitest

[pypitest]
repository: testpypi.python.org/pypi
username: gakonorde 
password: [my_password]

[pypi]
repository: upload.pypi.org/legacy
username: gakonorde
password: [my_password]
```

Comment: You won't see any input after the `Enter your password:` prompt, because it's hiding your password. Where did you put your `.pypirc` file? Can you share the contents (with your password redacted)?

Comment: The ```.pypirc``` file is in the same folder as ```.setup```, ```README```, ```License```, ```dict/``` etc. It's content is as follows:

```
[distutils]
index-servers =
    pypi
    pypitest

[pypitest]
repository: https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/
username: gakonorde
password: [my_password]

[pypi]
repository: https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
username: gakonorde
password: [my_password]
```

(In my case, for main and text versions of Pypi the account names are the same, and sorry for formatting the code here - I'm new to Stackoverflow)

Comment: I've edited your question, in the future you can add updates and clarifications there instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With regards to the password prompt, you won't see any input after the Enter your password: prompt, because it's hiding your password.

For your `.pypirc` file, this should be in your home directory (`~/.pypirc`), not in the same directory as your `setup.py` file.

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped!

Answer (score 5):

Solved with

```
python -m twine upload -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD dist/*
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting `pypi.org` and `test.pypi.org` are in different domains so they require you to register both domains.

official doc uses the test domain for explaining the steps:

```
python3 -m twine upload --repository testpypi dist/*
```